# Coloring a range of values in a 2D scatter plot with the same color

Tags: plotting

I want to give different color to the two bands of points as shown in the graph. How to do so?
[image]

Comment: If all your data is in one big list `data = {{x1, y1}, ...}` then the first thing that comes to my mind is `lowband = Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; y < 3]; highband = Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; y > 3]; ListPlot[{lowband, highband}]`

Comment: You should post the code you used for the plot, and maybe a data sample, now we have to guess what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

```
upper = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, RandomReal[{4.5, 6.5}, 100]];
lower = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, RandomReal[2.5, 100]];
data = Join @@ {lower, upper};

ListPlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[Pick[data, #[[2]]<=3& /@ data, #] & /@ {True, False}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]

(* or ) ListPlot[Style[#, If[#[[2]] <= 3, Red, Green]] & /@ data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]